# How to implement session.add on this code:

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, I need some help to make this script run faster, below is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob,os, csv
from sqlalchemy import *

count = 0
served_imsi = []
served_imei = []
served_msisdn = []
sgsn_address = []
ggsn_address = []
charging_id = []
apn_network = []
location_area_code = []
routing_area = []
cell_identity = []
service_area_code = []
s_charging_characteristics = []
plmn_id = []

path = '/home/cneps/cdr/*.cdr'
for file in glob.glob(path):
    f = open(file)
    for lines in f:
        served_imsi.append(lines[17:17+16])
        served_imei.append(lines[47:47+16])
        served_msisdn.append(lines[65:65+18])
        sgsn_address.append(lines[83:83+32])
        ggsn_address.append(lines[115:115+32])
        charging_id.append(lines[147:147+10])
        apn_network.append(lines[157:157+63])
        location_area_code.append(lines[296:296+4])
        routing_area.append(lines[300:300+2])
        cell_identity.append(lines[302:302+4])
        service_area_code.append(lines[306:306+4])
        s_charging_characteristics.append(lines[325:325+2])
        plmn_id.append(lines[327:327+6])

db = create_engine('sqlite:///CDR.db',echo=False)
metadata = MetaData(db)
CDRS = Table('CDRS', metadata, autoload=True)
i = CDRS.insert()

while count < len(served_imei):

        i.execute(Served_IMSI=served_imsi[count],
        Served_IMEI=served_imei[count],
        Served_MSISDN=served_msisdn[count],
        SGSN_Address=sgsn_address[count],
        GGSN_Address=ggsn_address[count],
        Charging_ID=charging_id[count],
        APN_Network=apn_network[count],
        LAC=location_area_code[count],
        RAC=routing_area[count],
        Cell_Identity=cell_identity[count],
        Service_Area_Code=service_area_code[count],
        S_Charging_Characteristics=s_charging_characteristics[count],
        PLMN_ID=plmn_id[count])
        count += 1

for files in glob.glob(path):
        os.remove(files)
```

The code is fine. But it takes too long, I asked a friend, and he suggested using session.add to make things faster.

The solution I came with was something like this:

```
for item in lists:
    session.add(item)
```

but that would work only for one list, and I have 14 lists.

Does anyone have an idea of how to implement session.add to my code, instead of execute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (primary) ways you can use SQLAlchemy. The way that you are currently doing it is using the [SQLAlchemy Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html) API. Using `session.Add` is part of the [Object Relational](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) API. They serve two separate purposes, and I would recommend reading some of the documentation to get an idea of the differences.

The Object Relational API (more generally referred to as [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), or "Object Relational Mapper") uses the SQLAlchemy Expression Language underneath, so anything you can do in the ORM API you can do in the SQLAlchemy Expression API (although with different syntax). So, I'd recommend that unless you really need to, don't try to switch your code over to the other API quite yet.

As an alternative to completely rewriting your code, note that you are doing this:

```
CDRS = Table('CDRS', metadata, autoload=True)
i = CDRS.insert()
```

`i` becomes an [insert expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#coretutorial-insert-expressions). You can use it to dynamically create insert statements. You can try this by printing out `i`: it will look like a SQL string with parameters (but note that the value is not actually a string; it is an object that helps automatically create a SQL string). When you pass that insert object over to the `execute` method (along with all of the parameters), the SQL string is generated an executed.

Right now, you are using the execute method on the insert statement. The preferred way is to use the execute method on the engine. So, instead of...

```
i.execute(...)
```

...you should do...

```
db.execute(i, ...)
```

The performance issue is that you are running into involves using `execute` once for each row. Thus, each INSERT is running in its own transaction, which could be slow. You could do something like...

```
all_data = []

while count < len(served_imei):
    data = {
        'Served_IMSI' : served_imsi[count],
        'Served_IMEI' : served_imei[count],
        ...
    }
    all_data.append(data)

    count += 1
```

Now, `all_data` contains a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing the keys (column names) and the values (column values) for the insert statement. Then, you can use...

```
db.execute(i, all_data)
```

I would recommend enabling `echo` while you are working on this to learn what SQLAlchemy is doing under the hood:

```
db = create_engine('sqlite:///CDR.db',echo=True) # Change `echo` from False to True
```

Your next step would be to remove your two loops, and create the dictionary that I just showed directly from the section of the code where are reading from the file. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob,os, csv
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('sqlite:///CDR.db',echo=False)
metadata = MetaData(db)
CDRS = Table('CDRS', metadata, autoload=True)
insert_statement = CDRS.insert()

all_data = []

path = '/home/cneps/cdr/*.cdr'
for file in glob.glob(path):
    # Use "with" to automatically close "f" when we're done with it.
    with open(file) as f:
        for lines in f:
            d = {
                'Served_IMSI' : lines[17:17+16],
                ....
            }
            all_data.append(d)

# No need for that "while count < len(served_imei)" loop, we can now just do...
db.execute(insert_statement, all_data)
```

Comment: Hello Mark, Thank you very much for your reply. I just didn't get what you mean by removing the two loops, which two loops? Do you mean inserting this code to create the dictionary right below "f = open(file) ?

Comment: I've modified my answer, hopefully that helps explain what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

For one I'd create a class eg. CDRItem like :

```
class CDRItem(db.Session):
    def __init__(served_imsi ....):
        served_imsi = self.served_imsi
```

and so on.
Then I'd iterate through cdr's line creating new CDRItem class objects and puting them into a list.
After the list creation all that's left is

```
session.add_all(created_list)
```

Comment: What is `db.Session`? I assume you mean `db.Model` from Flask-SQLAlchemy. If so, this question doesn't state that they are using Flask-SQLAlchemy.